# How do I customize the main login page for sharepoint where user chooses FBA or Windows Auth?

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, visual-studio-2013

I have a sharepoint site that uses Forms Based Authentication, Visual Studio 2013, Sharepoint 2013, and FBA Pack.  I have customized the FBA login page, by editing this file:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\3717_forms\Default.aspx (3717 being the port my FBA site is accessed at.)

in the browser, that pages URL is:

```
http://mymachine:3717/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F
```

However, before getting to that page, the user has to select, forms based, or windows authentication, the URL for that page in the browswer looks like this:

```
http://mymachine:3717/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F
```

it would seem to be that I would just go into the _login folder and find the default.aspx page to make my customizations here, as i went into the _forms folder to do the FBA customization, but the problem is, the _login folder does not exist.

Do you know where I might be able to find this page so that I can customize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the page should be

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN\default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this could work for you
[Link](http://garabound.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/crear-fba-auto-login-contra-windows-authentication/)

It's in spanish but work (written by me :P), Let me now if you need help

Comment: Please put the main content from the post in the answer, as link only answers become useless if the link is broken.